# How to print tree in an inorder traversal (java)?

Tags: java

I am trying to print my AVLtree as following,

```
. 50

55

. . 60

. 65

. . 70
```

– The entry for a node should be preceded by depth number of dots, where depth denotes the depth of the node in the tree.

root contains 55 and the left child contains 50, the right child contains 65, the right left child contains 60 and the right-right child contains 70 .

Below is my code so far. Can anyone help?

```
public string Display() {
    StringBulder sb= new StringBulder();
    inOrder (node,1,sb);
    return sb.toString();
}

// inorder traversal
public void inOrder (AVLNode<E> node, int depth, StringBuilde sb) {
    for (int i=1;i < depth; i++){
        sb.append(".");
    }

    if(node == null) return;

    inOrder(node.getleft(), depth+1,sb);
    sb.append(node.data);
    inOrder(node.getright(),depth+1,sb); 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific parts of it are giving you problems?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this is extremely easy.  Just increment a level parameter every time you recurse deeper.  Then, the number of dots is just the level.

Comment: Thank you @NullUserException, this what I wrote so far          public string Display() {
StringBulder sb= new StringBulder();
inOrder (node,1,sb);
return sb.toString();

// inorder traversal
public void inOrder (AVLNode<E> node, int depth, StringBuilde sb)
{
for (int i=1; i<depth; i++){
    sb.append(".");
  }
  
  if(node == null) return;

  inOrder(node.getleft(), depth+1,sb);

  sb.append(node.data);

  inOrder(node.getright(),depth+1,sb); 

}

Comment: @Renato Gama , I have written my code above!

Comment: @FrohaAlComputerya - Welcome to stackoverflow. Now that you we can see the code ;) can you update your question to describe a) what is wrong with the result and b) what part you are struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
void inOrder(AVLNode node, int depth, StringBuilder sb)
{
  if(node == null) return;

  inOrder(node.left, depth+1, sb);

  for(int a=0;a<depth;a++) sb.append(".");
  sb.append(node.data + "\n");

  inOrder(node.right, depth+1, sb);

}
```

Comment: so did that solve your problem?

Comment: Im trying to use your code to see what would happen, thank you

Comment: With homework questions, it is preferable to explain what is wrong , rather than just posting code. ie "Teach a man to Fish" ;)

Comment: @Rushil  after applying your code it seems that the root 55 has 60 as the right child but the fact 60 is the right left child,, can u help me to fix it .. thank u :)

Comment: No, my code gives the same output as you've posted in your question.

Comment: And another thing, depth starts with 1, not 0. Level starts with 0. So 55 should have one dot before it, if you're talking about depth.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty easy. Just increment the depth by 1 for left and right nodes, and append depth number of dots to `sb`. Then append data. Do this in a recursive fashion.

Comment: Thank you @ryanwilson. I did what u said in my code above so do u thing my code is completely right!